# Applying the getMouse() function to one part of the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I am attempting to apply the getMouse() function to a specific part of the window, instead of the whole thing. I need the block that is clicked in to change color if it is 'rect1'. However if any other block is clicked, nothing should happen. I have attached the portion of my code which I feel relates to this in case anyone can be of any assistance.

```
#draw the grid 
for j in range (6):
    for i in range(6):
        sq_i = Rectangle(Point(20 + (40*i), 20 + (40*j)),
                         Point(60 + (40*i),60 + (40*j)))
        sq_i.draw(window)
        sq_i.setFill('white')
        sq_i.setOutline('grey')

#wait for a click 
window.getMouse ()

#turn the alotted region red
rect1 = Rectangle(Point(20 + (40*1), 20 + (40*1)),
                         Point(60 + (40*1), 60 + (40*1)))
rect1.setOutline('black')
rect1.draw(window)
rect1.setFill('brown')

#if the mouse is clicked in rect1, change the block color to black 
while window.getMouse() in rect1:
    rect1.setFill('black')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to understand what `window.getMouse() in rect1` does. Python's `in` operator works by turning `a in b` into the method call `b.__contains__(a)`. Unfortunately, the `Rectangle` class doesn't have a `__contains__` method. This your immediate problem.

So, you need to use a different test. I suggest using Python's chained comparison operators to do the bounds checking yourself (there doesn't seem to be any library support for this in the `graphics` module):

```
mouse = window.getMouse()
if rect1.p1.x < mouse.x < rect1.p2.x and rect1.p1.y < mouse.y < rect1.p2.y
    rect1.setFill("black")
```

Note that I've changed the `while` loop for an `if` statement. If you want to repeatedly test mouse clicks until one hits the rectangle, you probably want to loop on `while True` and then `break` if the tested condition is true:

```
while True:
    mouse = window.getMouse()
    if rect1.p1.x < mouse.x < rect1.p2.x and rect1.p1.y < mouse.y < rect1.p2.y
        rect1.setFill("black")
        break
```